# Azure Redis Cache development

Tags: c#, azure, redis

I am trying to implement Azure Redis Cache in my app. When I see the documents they say I have to define a cache storage in the Azure online tool. I am wondering is there a way to skip that step and use Redis for development without using the actual server thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Redis locally and use localhost. That might be one of your options even though I don't think it's faster.

[You can download it and install it from here.](http://redis.io/download)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar yeah, of course, but I can't paste the installer in here :) As simple as it seems this really is it.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Redis server locally, and start the experiment. But if you have decided to use Azure Redis, you should develop toward the real one as early as possible. Several reasons:

1. Azure Redis supports SSL and this is the default port. You should use this.
2. Azure Redis has high availability support through master slave.
3. Azure Redis provide Cluster support.
4. It might experience unexpected patching process causing temporarily data loss

These things are not easily setup and test locally.